# Unable to create custom indicator

Tags: javascript, anychart

Checked all the samples in here: https://www.anychart.com/products/anystock/gallery/Stock_Technical_Indicators/?theme=darkEarth All are calculated by any chart functions. indicatorPlot is getting members like .adl etc..

Also checked the sample here with setCalculationFunction: https://www.anychart.com/blog/2018/03/14/custom-technical-indicators-javascript-stock-charts/

Is there a way to "map indicatorPlot" with a csv values like drawing the main graph? Or is datatable can store indicator values to show underneath the chart like oscilators.

The main question is: Is there a way to display a custom oscillator under the chart feeded with values from csv, json etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case, the indicator is a usual series that is based on your data. Simply create a series from your data, provide the desired name and that's it.